# Change tab on button click event

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

i would like to change to a different tab when i click a button.
my xaml is as follow:

```
<TabControl Name="Tabcontrol1" Margin=" 5" SelectedIndex="0">
            <TabItem Header="Properties" Opacity="1">
                <Grid Width="1185" Height="945" Background="Snow" >
</Grid>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Others">
<Grid>
</Grid>
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

and my button click event:

```
    private void BuildButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = "1";
}
```

is there something wrong? "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'" appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes:
`Tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 1;`

Comment: you can take me a reputation ;)